# After passing pointer to the main function, cannot print the content properly

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I am practicing using pointers to create objects and access data. I created a stuct called BigNum to represent a number with multiple digits. When I try to print the content of the struct inside the readDigits function, it can be printed pretty well. However, after passing the pointer to the main function, the content of the stuct is printed out to be random numbers. Why? How to fix it?

```
struct BigNum{
    int numDigits;    //the number of digits
    int *digits;  //the content of the big num
};

int main(){
    BigNum *numPtr = readDigits();
    for (int i=0; i<(numPtr->numDigits);i++ ){
       std::cout << (numPtr->digits)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

BigNum* readDigits(){
    std::string digits;
    std::cout << "Input a big number:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> digits; 

    int result[digits.length()];
    toInt(digits,result);

    BigNum *numPtr = new BigNum();
    numPtr->numDigits = digits.length();
    numPtr->digits = result;

/*     When I try to print in here, it's totally okay!

    std::cout << "Here is the content:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<numPtr->numDigits;i++ ){
    std::cout << (numPtr->digits)[i] << std::endl;
    }
    */

    return numPtr;
}

void toInt(std::string& str, int result[]){
    for (int i=0;i<str.length() ;i++ ){
    result[str.length()-i-1] = (int)(str[i]-'0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Dangling pointer dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BigNum* readDigits(){
    //....
    int result[digits.length()];
    //....
    numPtr->digits = result;


    return numPtr;
}
```

`result` is stored on the stack. So if you return it as part of `numPtr`, it will be invalid as soon as you exit the function. Instead of storing it on the stack you have to allocate it with `new`.

Comment: This answer is correct. It also opens up memory leak problems. Better to learn to use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Do I have to use "new" to fix it? Any other alternative way?

Comment: as Chris suggests, using a `vector<int>` as return value of the `readDigits` function is better

Comment: It's _almost_ correct. Let's leave out notions of "on the stack" and talk about storage duration / scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior because you assign address of automatic object to `digits` pointer. When `readDigits()` returns this memory is not valid anymore. You should assign to this pointer address of heap-based object (or some equivalent, e.g. use vector or smart pointer):

```
#include <vector>

struct BigNum{
    int numDigits;            //the number of digits
    std::vector<int> digits;  //the content of the big num
};
```

Then you can insert numbers into vector this way:

```
int input;
while ( std::cin >> input) //enter any non-integer to end the loop
{
   digits.push_back(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that within the function `BigNum* readDigits()` you assign apointer to stack memory to the pointer of your newly allocated BigNum:

```
int result[digits.length()];   // <--- variable is on the stack!!!
toInt(digits,result);

BigNum *numPtr = new BigNum();
numPtr->numDigits = digits.length();
numPtr->digits = result;   // <--- make pointer to stack memory available to caller of readDigits
```

Now if you proceed the access to numPtr->digits is ok since the memory of result is still valid on the stack (as long as you are within readDigits). Once you've left ´readDigits()´ the memory of result is overwritten depending on what you do (calling other functions, ...).

Right now I'm even wondering why you don't get a compiler error with ´int result[digits.length()];´ since ´digits.length()´ is not constant and the size of required stack memory has to be defined at compile time... so I'm thinking that the size of result is actually 0...?? Would be a nice thing to test!

My recommendation is to modify the code of readDigits as follows:

```
BigNum* readDigits()
{
    std::string digits;
    int i;

    std::cout << "Input a big number:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> digits; 

    //int result[digits.length()];
    //toInt(digits,result);

    BigNum *numPtr = new BigNum();
    numPtr->numDigits = digits.length();
    numPtr->digits = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numPtr->numDigits);   // allocate heap memory for digits

    toInt(digits, numPtr->digits);

    /*     When I try to print in here, it's totally okay!

    std::cout << "Here is the content:" << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i  <numPtr->numDigits; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (numPtr->digits)[i] << std::endl;
    }
    */

    return numPtr;
}
```

Remember to free your memory if ´BigNum *numPtr´ is no longer used (´free(numPtr->digits);´) otherwise you'll get a memory leak (sooner or later):

```
int main()
{
    BigNum *numPtr = readDigits();
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (numPtr->numDigits); i++)
    {
        std::cout << (numPtr->digits)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    free(numPtr->digits);   // free memory allocated by readDigits(..)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's not use this outdated and outmoded "on the stack" terminology, and instead talk usefully about storage duration / scope.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Outdated or not but that's where the variable is. I agree that in the context of classes it is more uniform to  talk about variable scopes. But I can't turn off my embedded programmers soul...

Comment: No, you have _no idea whatsoever_ whether that's where the variable is. Absolutely none!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then do a little experiment: Write a little function with no parameters which increments a global variable and calls itself. Wait for the stack overflow and check the number of recursions done. Then add let's say `int x[20];` to the function and run it again. If you check the number of recursions you will see a difference. Knowing your stack size you will notice that the difference is bigger than simply and int * pushed onto the stack. Therefore int x[20] is on the stack (and `int result[digits.length()];` is basically the same). You may also check the disassembly...

Comment: ...which may well vary even between builds. There is a reason that we talk in abstract terms. Your observations often hold true, but cannot be relied upon or assumed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The only thing I can think of is a function whose argument(s)/variable(s) fit into registers or the compiler optimizes a variable. But something like an `int x[20]` will not fit into registers of most processors and it is higly unlikely to be optimized. Furthermore I don't see an advantage why the compiler should allocate the memory somewhere else and risk memory fragmentation? Can you give an example when this happens or a link to some compiler documentation describing this behavior?

Comment: You're still missing the point and if you don't get it then unfortunately I don't believe I can explain it to you in a comment! C++ defines an abstract machine and it is useful to discuss it in that context, rather than confusing the world with arbitrary realisms that may or may not be true. Why not talk in the terms used in the C++ standard, about concepts defined by the C++ standard, so that we may look them up and verify them and know them to be true? It shouldn't be "I'll say 'on the stack' until you can do 3 months' research to find me a counterexample."